# Django template tag vs include for nav

Tags: django, django-templates

New to Django and using the template engine for the first time. My question is...

I have a navigation div in my base.html. Now in other languages I would use a include for nav element of the html. In Django I see we have something called a template tag. So should I use template tag to display presentation elements like nav or old school includes (which I believe Django also supports)?

Also to keep this a stackoverflow question, an example would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template tags are really for applying special processing to achieve the output you want. Using a template tag gives you access to all the functionality of the python language. The django template language is much more simple.

I would suggest that you want to stick with include rather than write a template tag. It will be easier to read.

Remember that you should be producing your list of variables in the view (or somewhere outside the template / template tag).

```
def your_view(request):
    #...
    nav_items = Category.objects.filter(include_in_nav=True)
    return render(request, 'your_page.html', {'nav_items': nav_items})
```

Then in your_page.html you're going to do -

```
{% include 'nav.html' %}
```

Then `nav.html` will be something like -

```
<nav>
    {% for item in nav_items %}
        <a href="{% url cat_page item %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Have a look at the docs on [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/) and [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: thank you for this well written answer, perfect just the info I was after

Comment: Any thing of note between the two approaches vis-a-vis `performance`?